# Number of real-time events is over the real-time event count daily limit. Event is no longer real-time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is there anything I need to worry about when I get these messages in my log?

[image]

```
2018-09-02 21:27:09.723503+0100 Songvote[1775:490365] 4.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023104] Number of real-time events is over the real-time event count daily limit. Event is no longer real-time. Event name, parameters: _vs, {
    "_c" = 1;
    "_o" = auto;
    "_pc" = CodeViewController;
    "_pi" = 1971604679964194266;
    "_sc" = UserViewController;
    "_si" = 1971604679964194267;
}

2018-09-02 21:27:09.723620+0100 Songvote[1775:490365] 4.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023104] Number of real-time events is over the real-time event count daily limit. Event is no longer real-time. Event name, parameters: _vs, {
    "_c" = 1;
    "_o" = auto;
    "_pc" = UserViewController;
    "_pi" = 1971604679964194267;
    "_sc" = ViewController;
    "_si" = 1971604679964194260;
}

2018-09-02 21:27:09.724009+0100 Songvote[1775:490365] 4.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023104] Number of real-time events is over the real-time event count daily limit. Event is no longer real-time. Event name, parameters: _vs, {
    "_c" = 1;
    "_o" = auto;
    "_pc" = ViewController;
    "_pi" = 1971604679964194260;
    "_sc" = CodeViewController;
    "_si" = 1971604679964194268;
}
```

I get these messages when my app is in the background, when it is meant to send data/analytics.

I am on the free plan, and I am no-where near the limits of the `Spark` plan.

What do these messages mean? Are they something I need to take into consideration?

May it be that too much analytics data is on the device, therefore needs to be sent to the cloud?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Comment: That message is coming from Google Analytics for Firebase, not Realtime Database.

Comment: @DougStevenson What does it mean then?

Comment: Sorry.  If I knew, I'd answer the question.  But it's clearly coming from analytics.

Comment: @DougStevenson No problem, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Is this a device you have AnalyticsDebugging turned on for?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman Hey Todd, you did great videos for the Firebase team! I currently do not use the Firebase right now, as I am a bit confused on how to do T&C's and all the rest of it... I was just testing out the technology. When testing my old project now, I get the warnings when I go to the home screen, and I assume the logs mean that data is being sent to my Firebase Analytics. I do not know if `AnalyticsDebugging` is on (not sure what it is), but I do have `-noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` set in my scheme.

Comment: please write here your pod file. It is help to fix your prolbem.

Comment: Did you ever resolve these messages? I get a lot of them and I think they may be contributing to a laggy UI

Comment: @mbby No, moved away from using the Firebase SDK a long while ago and then later dropped using the API completely and moved away.